# detect a wrinkles on face in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I would like to know something about wrinkles detection in Matlab:

[image: here is an example image]

I thought of using Hough Transform but it could not work for this. Is there any idea that I could processed further?
I even thought of using sobe, canny and other edge detector. But when I read their documentation, they are not really an edge detector.

```
close all
clear all
clc
Image = imread('imagename.jpg');
GrayImage = rgb2gray(Image);
FiltImage = edge(GrayImage ,'sobel');
imshow(FiltImage)
```

i want all the wrinkles as white pixel and the rest of the image as black.

Comment: 'they are not really an edge detector' they most certainly are. The Hough transform is useful to detect straight lines and circles, not to segment features. Can you be more specific about what you wish to achieve?

Comment: Could you also add an image where you give an idea, e.g. by drawing in red manually, which lines you want to detect? Do you want to detect the large lines in the forehead? Do you want to detect the small ones around the chin and cheek or both for example? It's difficult to know the accuracy you are after without it.

Comment: thanks jigg i want an output image which shows white line in place of wrinkles and rest  black.......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I borrowed the method used in vessel detection from the paper [Hessian-based Multiscale Vessel Enhancement Filtering](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/5670/Zhang.pdf) by Frangi et al. There is a Matlab implementation, [FrangiFilter2D](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter/content/FrangiFilter2D.m), that works on 2D vessel images. And I tried to apply it to wrinkle detection.

```
options = struct('FrangiScaleRange', [5 5], 'FrangiScaleRatio', 1, 'FrangiBetaOne', 1,...
           'FrangiBetaTwo', 500, 'verbose',true,'BlackWhite',true);
[outIm,whatScale,Direction] = FrangiFilter2D(double(GrayImage), options);
imshow(uint8(outIm/max(outIm(:))*256))
```

It looks better than pure edge extraction, though some improvement is need by (i) tuning the parameters, and (ii) combining with other image processing strategies.

[image]

Comment: Dear! this is pretty nice and i think i it is far better than my output result . i dont know whether i can ask this or not .But could you please  tell where i can find this code ?

Comment: sorry I added the wrong link, now it's updated in the answer: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter/content/FrangiFilter2D.m Thanks.

Comment: Thanks alot. i will check for more cases and i hope it will give me some better Result.

Comment: can i have this method in python please

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has a ton of fun tools that you can essentially play with in combination, to detect the wrinkles.  Here are some things to look at.
1). Study thresholding and see how it applies to your situation (this will help you a lot because of the contrast that exists between the wrinkles and the rest of the face color).

2). Remember you can add and subtract images.

3).Study watershed algorithm if you feel adventurous.

Comment: Thanks Dear! now i will look for watershed algorithm . i hope it will help me.....

Comment: sorry there is no one stepper, you gotta play with a variety of tools...as I am sure you know

Comment: Thanks alot. i will check for more cases and i hope it will give me some better Result.